# Как взаимодействуют программы, написанные на разных языках?

Tags: c#, c++, модули

Разработка одной большой программы, используя модули, написанные на разных языках - не новое слово в программировании. Однако мне стало интересно как модули взаимодействуют друг с другом? Все мои познания на эту тему ограничиваются тем, что между модулями должен быть какой-то общий формат - API. Но как эти API работают?

Предположим есть библиотека на С# и программа на С++. Если библиотека будет результат работы выводить в JSON файл, а с++ программа читать этот файл, то это приведет к крайне медленной работе. Так как модули на разных языках взаимодействуют между собой быстро?

Comment: Да, API, вы можете из C# вызывать функции dll, написанной на C++, но API так же используется в Web, те самые, которые в виде json.
Так же если вы прям хотите передать данные между программами, то можно использовать обычные файлы или же что лучше, MemoryStream, который размещается в оперативной памяти

Comment: @Yotic насчет MemoryStream. Я так понимаю, что библиотека должна поддерживать этот способ? Предположим, у меня есть C# библиотека, я хочу получить ее вывод. Но она лишь может писать в JSON файлик. Меня это не устраивает ввиду низкой скорости обращения к файловой системе. Никак данные с библиотеки не вытянуть?

Comment: Да, тогда вообще никак по другому, ищи исходный код и изменяй сам

Comment: @Yotic а если захукать функцию в библиотеке на другом языке? Получится ли вытянуть данные и не будет ли конфликтов?

Comment: Если в библиотеке нужный вам метод использует связку более низко уровневых методов, то вы можете так же их вызвать и уже использовать свой метод сохранения, но я думаю что такого не произойдёт

Comment: Шарповая библиотека реализует COM экспорт? Если нет, то вы никак не сможете ее использовать из C++. В таком случае вам придется писать для нее управляемую обертку так же на шарпе. Вопрос о сферических библиотеках в вакууме в принципе не может быть отвечен. Так же не понятно, что вас останавлиаает от написания софта на шарпе, вроде проще же, чем плюсы.

Comment: @Yotic `MemoryStream` - управляемый класс, вы никак не сможете его перекинуть в C++ как данные. А вот `byte[]` сможете, потому что он легко смаршалируется при экспорте. Будьте внимательны в своих советах.

Comment: @aepot, Я говорю о том, что приложение C++ и C# не будет использовать сторонних библиотек, то есть C# создаёт MemoryStream, а т.к MemoryStream - это просто удобная оболочка byte[], её можно считывать по адресам с помощью программы C++

Comment: @Yotic я как раз и говорю, что не можно. И толку от нее никакого, если только передать куда-то, где нужен именно поток. Или принять откуда-то. Когда можно использовать массив - надо использовать массив и невыеживаться) потому что это единственный представитель куска памяти в .NET, все остальное - обертки над ним.